# From Bash -> Docker by name -> Ruby -> Clear Cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, docker

So, I'm trying to create a bash script to clear the cache on a containerized docker instance on my system, as a single fire-and-forget command on a legacy codebase.

My current attempt has led me to the following script, which doesn't work:

Clear_container_cache.sh

```
docker exec -it <my_image_name> bundle exec rake Rails.cache.clear
```

What would be a reliable way to do this? The containers are hosted on a mac, the containers are Linux, and of course ruby is running rails on the container.

*Local Machine:* Mac Mojave

*Base Image:* CentOS Linux 7 (customized base)

*Rails Version:* 4.1.16

***Update:*** 
Per ZedTuX's suggestion, tried the following:

```
docker exec -it <container_name> bundle exec rails runner 'Rails.cache.clear'
```

which gives

> `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"bundle\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`

And running

```
docker-compose exec containership_hspweb_1 bundle exec rails runner 'Rails.cache.clear'
```

Errors out due to lack of a yml configuration file (which doesn't exist, due to being dynamically created and destroyed during runtime.)

As a note,

```
bundle exec rails runner 'Rails.cache.clear'
```

does work when run directly in the container.

Comment: You need to `bash` or `sh` first then run the bundle. Which linux do you use for that ?

Comment: Try `docker exec -it <my_image_name> bin/bundle exec rake Rails.cache.clear`

Comment: I'm on a mac, so unix. 
As for the bin addition, gave me this: ``OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"bin/bundle\": stat bin/bundle: no such file or directory": unknown```

Comment: Does `bundle exec rake Rails.cache.clear` work outside of docker? I would think not.

Comment: No. Don't have rails installed outside of docker even for it to run on.

Comment: @liljoshu `sudo docker exec -d $( sudo docker ps | grep name_of_my_image | awk "{print \$1}" | head -n 1 ) bin/rake tmp:cache:clear`

Comment: Same error, basically.

Comment: Says the problem is bin/rake instead of bin/bundle.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting while running the above command? Also, what is the rails version you are using?

Comment: Rails 4.1.16
Error as stated in question: ```OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"bundle\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown```

Running 7urkm3n's suggestion gives: ```Error response from daemon: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"bin/rake\": stat bin/rake: no such file or directory": unknown```

Comment: what is your base image ?

Comment: How about using 
docker exec -it <container_name> bash -c "bundle exec rails runner 'Rails.cache.clear'" ?
 It asks the bash to run the bundle command, you can use bash/sh whichever is available in the container.

Comment: @Yuva That one did it. That's the correct answer. It works. Post it up and get the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posting my comment as an answer.*

Use the below command

`docker exec -it <container_name> bash -c "bundle exec rails runner 'Rails.cache.clear'"`.

It asks the bash to run the bundle command, you can use bash/sh whichever is available in the container.

Answer (score 3):

Definitively your question lacks of information like the `Dockerfile` you're using to build your image, the Rails version your are using, but with some assumptions, here is how I can help you:

Assuming:

- `my_image_name` is a container including the Rails framework and bundler
- you are running Rails 5/6

#### Rails.cache.clear wouldn't work with Rake

You are trying to run `rake` but you give it a Ruby/Rails code to execute as a parameter. After solving the "bundle: no such file or directory" error, you would anyway end with the following error:

```
Don't know how to build task 'Rails.cache.clear' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)
```

Rake takes rake tasks as arguments like `db:migrate`, not Ruby/Rails code.

In order to execute the Ruby/Rails code `Rails.cache.clear` from the console, you will have to use `rails runner` (or `rails r`) like so:

```
bundle exec rails runner 'Rails.cache.clear'
```

### With docker-compose

It looks really strange in 2019 to use `docker exec` in a project, so I guess you are actually using Docker compose, so you should go with `docker-compose exec` instead:

```
docker-compose exec <container_name> bundle exec rails runner 'Rails.cache.clear'
```

`container_name` is the service name defined in the `docker-compose.yml` file, like `app` or `web`.

### With docker

Anyways, I can imagine you have a really good use case for `docker exec` so here is the same command for Docker:

```
docker exec -it <container_name> bundle exec rails runner 'Rails.cache.clear'
```

### But I still have "exec: \"bin/bundle\": stat bin/bundle: no such file or directory"

That means you have an issue in the way you've built your `Dockerfile`.
Without its content we can't help you, but there are plenty of blog articles explaining how to build a Rails `Dockerfile` which works, like:

- [the official Docker documentation page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/)
- In the case you're using the Rails Asset Pipeline: [Dockerizing a Rails application](https://iridakos.com/programming/2019/04/07/dockerizing-a-rails-application)
- In the case you are using Webpack: [Running a Rails app with Webpacker and Docker](https://medium.com/@dirkdk/running-a-rails-app-with-webpacker-and-docker-8d29153d3446)

That should help you enough to get rid of this error.

BTW `my_image_name` should be `my_container_name` as you're running containers based on images, and not running images.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still fairly new to really messing with docker and rails, so this was all very useful information. Going to test it all out and then throw you the vote if it works.

Comment: Running rails 4, and still getting error. I'm dealing with some legacy code here, sorry.

Comment: As I said, "Without it (The `Dockerfile`) content we can't help you ..."

Comment: Read the articles I gave you if you can't share that file.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you have `sh` or `bash` you can try:

```
docker exec -it <my_image_name> sh -c 'bundle exec rake Rails.cache.clear'
```

or

```
docker exec -it <my_image_name> bash -c 'bundle exec rake Rails.cache.clear'
```